# jquery UI tabs: function does not work in ajax tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am using JQuery UI tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="ajax/neobrabotannie.php" id="neobrabotannie">Необработанные</a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/klienti.php" id="klienti">Клиенты</a></li>                            
            </ul>
</div>

$('#test').click(function() {
 alert("clicked!");
});
```

If I open klienti.php tab click function does not work.

klienti.php:

```
<?
echo "<div id='test'>Test div.</div>";
?>
```

Tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code is not really coherent, you're using $("#test") but there is no element with id 'test' in the html code. Also, where are you calling $("#tabs").tabs() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery tabs with ajax, the HTML from the ajax call is not immediately available.

I believe your code to add a event for the click of the `test` id needs to be done within the [add](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-add) event of your tabs object.  So you have to add something like this to the `document.ready` handler in your JavaScript code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   add: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```